Combining small files into bigger ones didn't help improve storage efficiency on HDFS
On my HDFS, the block size is 512 MB.
I have an offline flow which generates data daily and outputs the data to HDFS.
I saw many small files (several KB) generated, so I updated the flow, making it combined the small files before outputting them to HDFS.
I DID see small files (several KB) combined as bigger files (several GB) on HDFS.
Before I applied the change, I executed the original flow for testing.
Before the test:
$ hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v /jobs/myflow
       QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
      48.8 K          25.8 K            20 T           9.4 T          122       22.9 K              3.5 T /jobs/myflow

After the test:
$ hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v /jobs/myflow
       QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
      48.8 K          23.3 K            20 T           7.9 T          130       25.4 K              4.0 T /jobs/myflow

After I applied the change, I executed the updated flow for testing.
Before the test:
$ hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v /jobs/myflow
       QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
      48.8 K          29.3 K            20 T           7.8 T          130       19.4 K              4.1 T /jobs/myflow

After the test:
$ hdfs dfs -count -q -h -v /jobs/myflow
       QUOTA       REM_QUOTA     SPACE_QUOTA REM_SPACE_QUOTA    DIR_COUNT   FILE_COUNT       CONTENT_SIZE PATHNAME
      48.8 K          28.9 K            20 T           6.3 T          138       19.7 K              4.6 T /jobs/myflow

Obviously, before the change, the flow generated 2.5 K (25.8 K - 23.3 K) files, while after the change, the flow generated only 0.4 K (29.3 K - 28.9 K) files.
Therefore, from my understanding, the storage consumption should have become smaller after the change, because bigger files occupy less blocks (again, 512 MB per block) on HDFS.
However, the fact is that the storage consumption kept unchanged as 1.5 T (9.4 T - 7.9 T = 1.5 T; 7.8 T - 6.3 T = 1.5 T).
Can someone please help me understand it?
